# Applied/Numerical Linear Algebra-Suggestions for Project

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra, research

I am looking for suggestions for a research project in applied/numerical linear algebra. As far as requirements, there really aren't any except that the topic has to tie in somehow with numerical methods used to solve problems in linear algebra. One suggestion that popped up was "Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) and image processing". The text we are using is "Applied Numerical Linear Algebra" by James W. Demmel, and we are expected to understand the material at least at that level. Any suggestions are most welcome, thanks!

Comment: Computation of low rank approximations as given in the book by : Ivan Markovsky. Low rank approximations are really important in image processing. But, when we taks a LRA some of the properties of the original matrices get lost. The problem is to find a low rank approximation with the same properties as the original matrix. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be too advanced, but there's the discrete Radon transform. The idea is basically: say you have a matrix of unknown numbers, you take as your data the sum along any row, column, or diagonal, and your goal is to recover the original numbers.

This paper by Beylkin should be understandable to someone with your background:
http://amath.colorado.edu/pub/wavelets/papers/BEYLKI-1987.pdf

A key tool in the inversion process is the fast Fourier transform (FFT) which is perhaps the most important numerical algorithm ever. The abstract notion of a Fourier transform is also very important to signal processing (and endless other branches of mathematics).

One application is to medical imaging / the CT scan: if the numbers are density of tissue inside someone's body, the sum along a line (row/column/etc.) corresponds to the attenuation of an x-ray passing through that tissue. Thus, by probing someone's body with x-rays, you map the density of the stuff inside them.

The continuous analog of this is the Radon transform / X-ray transform, and they require some heavier math, but I would still recommend reading about them as background.

Comment: This is a great suggestion-thanks! However, how would you go about showing that the algorithms discussed actually work as expected? One way would be to get a CT/X-ray machine, but that is not as practical... do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Well, I don't know what level of detail you should need to include, but you can show the discrete numerical algorithm works under the right hypotheses (you should have a grasp on this after reading the paper I linked), and you can claim the continuous version of this works (i.e. the transform can be inverted). Like I said, the continuous version is harder to understand, but maybe you can grasp some elements of the theory. When it comes to showing the application works, I would just talk about some of the people/successes involved (e.g. the Nobel prize for Hounsfield and Cormack),

Comment: and maybe touch on some of the engineering challenges (e.g. in the mathematical model of the continuous problem, the assumed data is the integral across *every* line, i.e. an infinite number of x-rays. This isn't safe nor even possible, and so one has to find a way to get a usable image from a limited set of line integrals.) You could also write a computer program to do the reconstruction in the discrete case, that would make for a good demonstration (there is also some ready-made python code (in scipy, I think) dealing with the discrete Radon transform.

Comment: Here are some notes on the continuous Radon transform http://www-math.mit.edu/~helgason/Radonbook.pdf Again, they will be harder to understand, but see if you can get the basic idea.

Comment: And the FFT is a very important tool on its own, so you could spend some time talking about its development, why it works, and other applications (no shortage here).